# How to make categories out of my text file and calculate average out of the numbers?

Tags: python

I am working on a assignment, but I am stuck and I do not know how to proceed.

I need to make different categories out of the different categories from the first line (from the txt file) and calculate averages over every numerical value. The program has to work flawless when I add new lines to the txt file.

```
Category;currency;sellerRating;Duration;endDay;ClosePrice;OpenPrice;Competitive?
Music/Movie/Game;US;3249;5;Mon;0,01;0,01;No
Music/Movie/Game;US;3249;5;Mon;0,01;0,01;No
Music/Movie/Game;US;3249;5;Mon;0,01;0,01;No
Music/Movie/Game;US;3249;5;Mon;0,01;0,01;No
Music/Movie/Game;US;3249;5;Mon;0,01;0,01;No
Music/Automotive/Game;US;3249;5;Mon;0,01;0,01;No
Music/Automotive/Game;US;3249;5;Mon;0,01;0,01;No
```

This is the text file. I tried to make different categories out of them, but I do not know if I did it correctly and how to let Python know that he has to calculate all the numbers from 1 group.

```
with open('bijlage2.txt') as bestand:
    maak_er_lists_van = [(line.strip()).split(';') for line in bestand]
keys = maak_er_lists_van[0]
lijst = list(zip([keys]*len(maak_er_lists_van[1:]),
maak_er_lists_van[1:]))
x = [zip(i[0], i[1]) for i in lijst]
maak_dict = [dict(i) for i in x]


for i in maak_dict:
    categorieen =[i['Category'], i['currency'], i['sellerRating'],
i['Duration'], i['endDay'], i['ClosePrice'], i['OpenPrice'],
i['Competitive?']]
    categorieen = list(map(int, categorieen))
```

This is what I have so far. I am a Python beginner so the whole text file thing is new to me. Can somebody help me or explain what I have to do so that I can work further on this project? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your text file really have those blank lines in it?

Comment: so, do you want to calculate averages over all values of one category, so let's say all `'sellerRating'` values from all lines, or over all values from one line?

Comment: The file does not have blank lines in it, and i want to calculate averages over all values of one category like 'sellerRating'

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. I had to add using `locale.atof()` because where I am `.` is used as the decimal point, not commas. You may have to change this as indicated.

The `csv` module is used to read the file, and the averages are computed in a two-step process. First the values for each category are summed, and then afterwards, the average value of each one is calculated based on the number of values read.

```
import csv
import locale
from pprint import pprint, pformat

import locale
#locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')  # empty string for platform's default settings
# Following used for testing to force ',' to be considered as a decimal point.
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'French_France.1252')

avg_names = 'sellerRating', 'Duration', 'ClosePrice', 'OpenPrice'
averages = {avg_name: 0 for avg_name in avg_names}  # Initialze.

# Find total of each category of interest.
num_values = 0
with open('bijlage2.txt', newline='') as bestand:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(bestand, delimiter=';')
    for row in csvreader:
        num_values += 1
        for avg_name in avg_names:
            averages[avg_name] += locale.atof(row[avg_name])

# Calculate average of each summed value.
for avg_name, total in averages.items():
    averages[avg_name] = total / num_values

print('raw results:')
pprint(averages)

print()  # Formatted output
print('Averages:')
for avg_name in avg_names:
    rounded = locale.format_string('%.2f', round(averages[avg_name], 2),
                                   grouping=True)
    print('  {:<13} {:>10}'.format(avg_name, rounded))
```

Output:

```
raw results:
{'ClosePrice': 0.01, 'Duration': 5.0, 'OpenPrice': 0.01, 'sellerRating': 3249.0}

Averages:
  sellerRating    3 249,00
  Duration            5,00
  ClosePrice          0,01
  OpenPrice           0,01
```

Comment: How can I remove the brackets and round the numbers up to 2 decimals?

Comment: By manually printing each entry in the `averages` dictionary. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with your way to read the file and creating a dictionary with the categories and values, imo. Your list `maak_dict` contains one dictionary for every line. To calculate an average for one category, you could do something like this:

```
def calc_average(categ):
    values = [i[categ] for i in maak_dict]
    average = sum(values)/len(values)
    return average
```

assuming that you want to calculate the mean average.  `categ` has to be a string.

After that, you can create a new dictionary that contains all the averages:

```
new_dict = {}
for category in maak_dict[0].keys():
    avg = calc_average(category)
    new_dict[category] = avg
```